# Is there split_copy or some kind of shortcut

Tags: c++, boost

Is anyone aware of a shortcut for `boost::split`. That

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
boost::split(args, argsString, boost::is_any_of("\t "), boost::token_compress_on);
```

becomes

```
auto const args = boost::split(args, argsString, boost::is_any_of("\t "), boost::token_compress_on);
or
auto const args = boost::split<std::vector>(args, argsString, boost::is_any_of("\t "), boost::token_compress_on);
```

Basically the same like there is, for example, one for `trim` - `trim_copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No shortcut exists in Boost as far as I know.
Personally, I wrote a simple wrapper for `split` because I had the same issue with it that you do:

```
template <typename RangeT, typename PredicateT>
std::vector<std::string> split(RangeT& Input, PredicateT Pred, 
                               boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type eCompress = boost::token_compress_off)
{
   std::vector<std::string> toReturn;
   boost::split(toReturn, Input, Pred, eCompress);
   return toReturn;
}
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H3hj8lNxfWaLGv1R)